# Why does two joined circles (wedge sum) with a point removed deformation retract to a single circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two unit circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $X$ is centered at $(1,0)$, while $Y$ is centered at $(-1,0)$.

Consider $A = X \cup Y$. Let $p \in Y$ be a point that is not $(0,0)$.

Why is $X$ a deformation retract of $A - p$?

**Attempt**: Intuitively, I can expand the hole in $Y$ and pushed both "arms" into the point $(0,0)$. But what would the retract $r: A - p \to X$ be exactly?

Also, the fact that $Y - p$ is homeomorphic to the real line via sterographic projection, and that the real line is contractible feels like I should be able to retract $Y-p$ to the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: You're talking about a deformation retraction and then referring to a retraction, which one are you after?

Comment: @AlexJBest - Deformation retract. I was trying to figure out a retract $r$ that I could use in the deformation retract.

Comment: I'm not sure it would help you much, for example $r\colon A- p \to X$ given by $r(x,y) = (x,y)$ if $x \ge 0$ and $r(x,y) = (0,0)$ otherwise is a retract but it doesn't really tell you anything about how the deformation might work. You have an answer now anyway though!

Comment: @AlexJBest- I am not sure if my lingo is correct, but that retract is not a deformation retract.

Comment: Ahhh, it's probably a definition thing, I was using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_retract#Definitions

Comment: @AlexJBest - I see. Its a retract. But its not a deformation retract. Any space $X$ has a retract to a point. $r(x) = x_0 \in X$. But the point need not be the deformation retract of $X$. But thanks for trying anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p = (-1 + \cos\psi, \sin\psi)$ for $\psi \in (-\pi, \pi)$. Consider $H: A\setminus\{p\} \times [0, 1] \to A\setminus\{p\}$ given by

$$H((-1+\cos\theta, \sin\theta), t) = \begin{cases}
(-1 + \cos((1-t)\psi-t\pi), \sin((1-t)\psi-t\pi)) & \theta \in (-\pi, \psi)\\
(-1 + \cos((1-t)\psi+t\pi), \sin((1-t)\psi+t\pi)) & \theta \in (\psi, \pi)
\end{cases}$$

and $H(x, t) = x$ otherwise. The first case retracts the bottom arc to $(0, 0)$ while the second case retracts the top arc to $(0, 0)$.

Comment: NICE. Thanks! +1 and accepted.